# redux-saga - How to get the watcher method - takeEvery - action type itself to update the redux store

Tags: redux-saga

Lets take for example the beginner documentation:

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html

```js
import { put, takeEvery, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'

const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

function* helloSaga() {
  console.log('Hello Sagas!')
}

function* incrementAsync() {
  yield delay(1000)
  yield put({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
}

function* watchIncrementAsync() {
  yield takeEvery('INCREMENT_ASYNC', incrementAsync)
}

// notice how we now only export the rootSaga
// single entry point to start all Sagas at once
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    helloSaga(),
    watchIncrementAsync()
  ])
}
```

The reducer will need to have detect INCREMENT_ASYNC, even though nothing on this action type actually changes the state. Otherwise we get error:

> error takeLatest$1 requires a pattern or channel

In anycase, thats fine, its just it seems wasteful to have an extra type doing nothing in the reducer itself.

Lets say I would rather have 1 type - INCREMENT_ASYNC, and remove  INCREMENT.

I want to populate my store with INCREMENT_ASYNC instead. How do mock this code up to pull the response from incrementAsync to update the INCREMENT_ASYNC action type?